# Laravel adldap2 - how to check by samaccountname instead of userprincipalname

Tags: laravel

how to change to locate users by `samaccountname` instead of `userprincipalname`?

Because I want to able to authenticate users with username like `user.name` instead of `user.name@mail.com`, but when I change from `userprincipalname` to `samaccountname` in `ldap_auth.php` file I get `Invalid credentials` error. Code:

```
    'ldap' => [

        'locate_users_by' => 'samaccountname',

        'bind_users_by' => 'distinguishedname',

    ],
```

How to fix this? Using newest adldap2 version and Laravel 5.8

Thanks for help in advance!:)

Comment: Once you change the file have you done php artisan config:clear and php artisan cache:clear? I've found this to hold on to configs before. Also, documentation https://adldap2.github.io/Adldap2-Laravel/#/auth/setup?id=username-column says you need to update your config so that the database column matches and the sync attributes also match.

Comment: Tried clearing cache and another method not helped, still have same error, because I'm using NoDatabaseUserProvider instead of DatabaseUserProvider so there is no difference :/

Comment: https://adldap2.github.io/Adldap2-Laravel/#/auth/setup?id=ldap Check the NOTE out that says: "For example, if you're executing an Auth::attempt(['username' => 'jdoe..']) and you have a locate_users_by value set to userprincipalname then the Adldap2-Laravel auth driver will try to retrieve your users username from the given credentials array with the key userprincipalname. This would generate an exception since this key does not exist in the above credentials array."

Comment: So that means key always be userprincipalname?

Comment: I think it means you need to pass the username with the key samaccountname. AS it stands, it is looking for the key userprincipalname in the auth request but it's missing as you've said you are using samaccountname.

Comment: My mistake sorry. I can authenticate, but I can't search because I'm getting Invalid credentials error using this: Adldap::connect('default', $username, $password)->search()->where('samaccountname', '=', $username)->first()

Comment: I'm using a slightly older version but I didn't use the Adldal::connect, I just used Adldap::search but in mt adldap.php config file I needed to declare ADLDAP_BASEDN, ADLDAP_ADMIN_ACCOUNT_SUFFIX, ADLDAP_ADMIN_USERNAME and ADLDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD. May well be that the admin account used to perform the query is not in the correct format.